# Swift 4 - Remove Items from array based off another array

Tags: swift

I have two table views

```
@IBOutlet var specialitiesAll: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var specialitiesAdded: UITableView!
```

and they each populate separate arrays

```
var allArray = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()

var addedArray = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()
```

One is populated with all items, the other is items the user added, both I get from an API

```
let newAddedArray = self.userProfile["specialities"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

for item in newAddedArray
{
      self.addedArray.append(["id" : item["id"]!, "text" : item["name"]!])
}

self.specialitiesAdded.reloadData()

getSpecialities(){ result in

      for item in result
      {
             self.allArray.append(["id" : item["id"]!, "text" : item["text"]!])
      }

      self.specialitiesAll.reloadData()

}
```

My question is allArray has all the items, how would I either remove or skip the items that are in addedArray or newAddedArray?

Comment: Why are you using `[String: Any]` to store your data? Use a class/struct instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert Array into Set and perform difference set processing. Hash table is very efficient and the order may be messy. Direct processing of Arrays is not efficient, but the order is guaranteed to be the same. According to the scene selection?

```
var employees: Set = ["Alicia", "Bethany", "Chris", "Diana", "Eric"]
let neighbors: Set = ["Bethany", "Eric", "Forlani", "Greta"]
employees.subtract(neighbors)
print(employees)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
extension Array {
    func containsObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        let anObject = object as AnyObject
        for obj in self {
            let anObj = obj as AnyObject
            return anObj.isEqual(anObject)
        }
        return false
    }
}

let array1: [[String: Any]] = [["a": 1, "b": "123"], ["c": 456.5]]
let array2: [[String: Any]] = [["a": 1, "b": "123"]]
let result = array1.filter{ !array2.containsObject($0) }
print(result) 
//[["c": 456.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go this route with no extensions

```
getSpecialities(){ result in

            for item in result
            {

                if (self.addedArray.contains(where: { $0["id"] as! Int == item["id"] as! Int }) == false) {

                    self.allArray.append(["id" : item["id"]!, "text" : item["text"]!])

                }

            }

            self.specialitiesAll.reloadData()

        }
```